# The type or namespace name 'readFullyStream' could not be found

Tags: c#, stream, streaming, mp3, naudio

Im tried to use NAudio demo app for MP3 Streaming in Csharp, when i tests thier demo it works perfectly. And i tried to create it in a c# form but i get a error. It says

> "Error    1   The type or namespace name 'readFullyStream' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\users\alioriyadho\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Form1.cs  89  47  WindowsFormsApplication5"

I don't know why i get error, i added all references and thinks like that.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class MP3StreamingPanel : Form
    {
        enum StreamingPlaybackState
        {
            Stopped,
            Playing,
            Buffering,
            Paused
        }

        public MP3StreamingPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.volumeSlider1.VolumeChanged += new EventHandler(volumeSlider1_VolumeChanged);
            this.Disposed += this.MP3StreamingPanel_Disposing;
        }

        void volumeSlider1_VolumeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.volumeProvider != null)
            {
                this.volumeProvider.Volume = this.volumeSlider1.Volume;
            }
        }

        private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
        private IWavePlayer waveOut;
        private volatile StreamingPlaybackState playbackState;
        private volatile bool fullyDownloaded;
        private HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        private VolumeWaveProvider16 volumeProvider;

        delegate void ShowErrorDelegate(string message);

        private void ShowError(string message)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new ShowErrorDelegate(ShowError), message);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        }

        private void StreamMP3(object state)
        {
            this.fullyDownloaded = false;
            string url = (string)state;
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse resp = null;
            try
            {
                resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (e.Status != WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
                {
                    ShowError(e.Message);
                }
                return;
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384 * 4]; // needs to be big enough to hold a decompressed frame

            IMp3FrameDecompressor decompressor = null;
            try
            {
                using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var readFullyStream = new readFullyStream(responseStream);
                    do
                    {
                        if (bufferedWaveProvider != null && bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes < bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 4)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Mp3Frame frame = null;
                            try
                            {
                                frame = Mp3Frame.LoadFromStream(readFullyStream);
                            }
                            catch (EndOfStreamException)
                            {
                                this.fullyDownloaded = true;
                                // reached the end of the MP3 file / stream
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (WebException)
                            {
                                // probably we have aborted download from the GUI thread
                                break;
                            }
                            if (decompressor == null)
                            {
                                // don't think these details matter too much - just help ACM select the right codec
                                // however, the buffered provider doesn't know what sample rate it is working at
                                // until we have a frame
                                WaveFormat waveFormat = new Mp3WaveFormat(frame.SampleRate, frame.ChannelMode == ChannelMode.Mono ? 1 : 2, frame.FrameLength, frame.BitRate);
                                decompressor = new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(waveFormat);
                                this.bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(decompressor.OutputFormat);
                                this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20); // allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
                                //this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration = 250;
                            }
                            int decompressed = decompressor.DecompressFrame(frame, buffer, 0);
                            //Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Decompressed a frame {0}", decompressed));
                            bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, decompressed);
                        }

                    } while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exiting");
                    // was doing this in a finally block, but for some reason
                    // we are hanging on response stream .Dispose so never get there
                    decompressor.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (decompressor != null)
                {
                    decompressor.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
                this.bufferedWaveProvider = null;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StreamMP3), textBoxStreamingUrl.Text);
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Paused)
            {
                playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
            }
        }

        private void StopPlayback()
        {
            if (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                if (!fullyDownloaded)
                {
                    webRequest.Abort();
                }
                this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped;
                if (waveOut != null)
                {
                    waveOut.Stop();
                    waveOut.Dispose();
                    waveOut = null;
                }
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                // n.b. streaming thread may not yet have exited
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ShowBufferState(0);
            }
        }

        private void ShowBufferState(double totalSeconds)
        {
            labelBuffered.Text = String.Format("{0:0.0}s", totalSeconds);
            progressBarBuffer.Value = (int)(totalSeconds * 1000);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                if (this.waveOut == null && this.bufferedWaveProvider != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Creating WaveOut Device");
                    this.waveOut = CreateWaveOut();
                    waveOut.PlaybackStopped += waveOut_PlaybackStopped;
                    this.volumeProvider = new VolumeWaveProvider16(bufferedWaveProvider);
                    this.volumeProvider.Volume = this.volumeSlider1.Volume;
                    waveOut.Init(volumeProvider);
                    progressBarBuffer.Maximum = (int)bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration.TotalMilliseconds;
                }
                else if (bufferedWaveProvider != null)
                {
                    var bufferedSeconds = bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration.TotalSeconds;
                    ShowBufferState(bufferedSeconds);
                    // make it stutter less if we buffer up a decent amount before playing
                    if (bufferedSeconds < 0.5 && this.playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Playing && !this.fullyDownloaded)
                    {
                        this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
                        waveOut.Pause();
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Paused to buffer, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                    }
                    else if (bufferedSeconds > 4 && this.playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering)
                    {
                        waveOut.Play();
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Started playing, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                        this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Playing;
                    }
                    else if (this.fullyDownloaded && bufferedSeconds == 0)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Reached end of stream");
                        StopPlayback();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private IWavePlayer CreateWaveOut()
        {
            return new WaveOut();
            //return new DirectSoundOut();
        }

        private void MP3StreamingPanel_Disposing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopPlayback();
        }

        private void buttonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Playing || playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering)
            {
                waveOut.Pause();
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("User requested Pause, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Paused;
            }
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StopPlayback();
        }

        private void waveOut_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Playback Stopped");
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Playback Error {0}", e.Exception.Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
                var readFullyStream = new readFullyStream(responseStream);
                do
```

"readFullyStream" in `new readFullyStream(responseStream)` needs to be a `Type` of some sort, probably located in your MP3 library.  Instead, you're using the same name as the variable you're trying to declare.

Comment: But the problem is the whole code worked very good on their demo app, i just copied the code and added the references to a new project and recived this error.

Comment: I really don't think you can declare a variable with the same name as a type, although I haven't actually tried it.  `readFullyStream` is camelCased; it's very unlikely that a library writer would write a C# class without giving it a PascalCased name.

Comment: I found the problem, there was a classes that i had to import to the project. It those files i needed 

    ReadFullyStream.cs
    INAudioDemoPlugin.cs

and of course

    Microsoft.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.Desktop.dll
    NAudio.dll
    NAudio.xml
    NSpeex.dll
    System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll

Comment: Is the class name really camelCased?  For the record, it's a really bad idea to name an instance variable the same as the type it is declaring.  Even if it works, it will be really confusing to anyone who has to read your code.